# Outlook 2016 Mac change order of accounts

Tags: email, ms-office

Is there any way to change the order that multiple accounts are shown in the left (folders) pane of Outlook 2016 Mac's main window?  Or do I have to delete the topmost account and add it again to move it lower in the list?

Here's more info about why I want to do this:

I'm a new user of Outlook Mac 2016. I added two mail accounts (work and personal) and I want to keep them visually separate in Outlook. So I unchecked the "Group similar folders, such as Inboxes, from different accounts". But now my personal email account (that I added first to Outlook) is on top and my work account is on the bottom.

I'd like to reverse this order because I spend more time on work email and want to keep it on top.

In the PC version of Outlook I can just drag one account above another. But that doesn't work on the Mac version. Is there another way to reorder the accounts in the Mac version?

I know I can just delete and re-add my personal account, but I was hoping to avoid having to wait hours for it to sync years of email.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wanted to know the same thing.  I searched and couldn't find an answer.  I finally figured it out myself.  You can change the "default" account and it will go to the top.  Go to Tools, Account and then select the account you want to be the default.  Click the gear at the bottom and select "Set as default."

Then, the remaining accounts will be put in alphabetical order.  You may need to exit Outlook and reopen it to see the new order.

This works better than deleting the top account - letting the items shuffle and then adding the other accounts below since the sort order doesn't always follow the order of addition to the app. Especially if you have delegate accounts you're adding.

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can identify the account inbox (and/or other folders) as favorite, which will move them to the top. Toggle (on/off) the star to the right of the folder in the main window. Version 15.36 (170702) moves non-Exchange accounts to the bottom regardless of default account.

Answer (score 3):

I just upgraded to Outlook for Mac 2016 and have 4 accounts - and of course my new client is at the bottom.  Something really easy - go into your accounts and just add A) account name   B) Account name  C) account name.  Its a little clunky but you see a nice list with the accounts in the order you want.  Good luck!

Comment: Sadly this appears to be the only way to do it beyond setting the default account.

Comment: Hi people from history. It is 2023. Still the method is same.

Answer (score 2):

After the default account, all of them are arranged in alphabetical order. So instead of numbering them, add an alpha bullet (e.g.: a. First Account, b. Second Account, c. Third Account, and so on)

Answer (score 1):

I added a number to front of each account description in the Accounts dialog box (e.g., "1. Main Email") so they fell into the order I need.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, none of these solutions worked for me. The only way to get the account i want on top is to make it the default. But I don't want that account to be the default.
I have tons of folders in my main exchange account and having my .mac account at the bottom in the Sidebar won't work for me. My exchange account is my primary account. But i need to see when my .mac account has new messages.